# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter getItemCount() always returns 0

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my Adapter class code:

```
class SearchPeopleAdapter(user: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<User>) :
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<User, SearchPeopleAdapter.ViewHolder>(user) {

    private var mUser : FirestoreRecyclerOptions<User>? = null

    private var mOptions: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<User>? = null
    private var mSnapshots: ObservableSnapshotArray<User>? = null

    init {
        mUser = user
    }

    fun firestoreRecyclerAdapter(user: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<User>?) {
        mOptions = user
        mSnapshots = user!!.snapshots
        if (mOptions!!.owner != null) {
            mOptions!!.owner!!.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
        }
    }

    override fun startListening() {
        if (!mSnapshots!!.isListening(this)) {
            mSnapshots!!.addChangeEventListener(this);
        }
    }

    override fun stopListening() {
        mSnapshots!!.removeChangeEventListener(this)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    //Inflate the xml
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.search_people_list_item, parent, false))
    }

    //Bind every dataView to the xml based on the Int value
    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, holderNumber: Int, user: User) {
        viewHolder.apply {
            itemView.search_people_person_list_name.text = user.Name
            itemView.search_people_person_username.text = user.UserName
        }
        viewHolder.bind(user)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mSnapshots!!.size
    }

    //Adds functionality to each View (aka ViewHolder) which is every person downloaded
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!), View.OnClickListener {
        //We are downloading User Objects so this Variable will be assigned to the UserObject downloaded
        var currentUser : User? = null
        //When the class is initiated this function is called which sets an OnClickListener to each View
        init {
            itemView!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        //The Data from the Object is used to Populate the TextViews
        fun bind(model: User) {
            currentUser = model
            itemView.search_people_person_list_name.text = model.Name
            itemView.search_people_person_username.text = model.UserName

            //If the user has set a profilePhoto then download & populate it with Glide
            if ( model.ProfilePhotoChosen ) {
                CompanionObjects.getPersonProfilePhotoStorageRef(model.Uid).downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    val downloadUrl = it.toString()
                    Glide.with(itemView)
                        .load(downloadUrl)
                        .into(itemView.search_people_list_profile_image)
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Timber.i("unable to retrieve your profile photo")
                }
            }
            //Clear the View with the Glide.with(View).clear() method as the view will be reused and the photo
            //might also get reused unnecessarily
            else {
                Glide.with(itemView).clear(itemView.search_people_list_profile_image)
            }

        }

        //The onClick function is called when the View is clicked, in this case we are starting
        // an Intent with the Intent Extra of userId to the PersonProfile Activity
        // which will check for the IntentExtras and Populate the elements
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val userId = currentUser!!.Uid
            Timber.i("The click is $userId")
            val intent = Intent(v!!.context, PersonProfileActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(CompanionObjects.USER_ID_INTENT_EXTRA, userId)
            v.context.startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

}
```

Here are 2 of the methods in the Activity class, Inspite of calling the onStart and onStop method, the itemCount method always returns 0

```
    override fun onStop() {
        adapter!!.stopListening()
        super.onStop()
    }

    //Retrieves data from Firestore and assigns the retrieved data to the search People Adapter
    private fun retrieveDataFromFirestore(searchQuery : String) {

        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        //Assigns the Collection Name from which needs to be queried
        //the where conditions ensure to query a userDocument whose userName starts with the query entered in the searchField
        val userNameQuery = mFirestore.collection(CompanionObjects.USERS_COLLECTION_NAME)
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("userName", searchQuery)
            .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("userName", "$searchQuery\uF7FF")

        //Assigns the query to the User Objects that are related to Firestore
        users = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
            .setQuery(userNameQuery, User::class.java)
            .build()

        //Assigns the Firestore queried data to the search People Adapter
        adapter = SearchPeopleAdapter(users!!)
        registerAdapterObserver()
        adapter!!.firestoreRecyclerAdapter(users!!)
        adapter!!.startListening()
        search_people_list.setHasFixedSize(true)
        search_people_list.hasFixedSize()
        search_people_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        search_people_list.adapter = adapter
        persistSearchQueryString(searchQuery)

    }
```

When I call getItemCount method in the Activity class. It always returns 0 even thou the adapter does hold Views. How do I retrieve the exact count in the Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this, Here is the code:

```
private fun retrieveDataFromFirestore(searchQuery : String) {

mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

 //Assigns the Collection Name from which needs to be queried
        //the where conditions ensure to query a userDocument whose userName 
 starts with the query entered in the searchField
        val userNameQuery = mFirestore.collection(CompanionObjects.USERS_COLLECTION_NAME)
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(userName, searchQuery.toLowerCase())
            .whereLessThanOrEqualTo(userName, "${searchQuery.toLowerCase()}\uF7FF")

        //Assign the Query to the user variable
        users = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
            .setQuery(userNameQuery, User::class.java)
            .build()

//Assigns the Firestore queried data to the search People Adapter
    adapter = object : SearchPeopleAdapter(users!!) {
        //Need to create a class Body because it is open and this gives
        //option to override its onDataChanged method in the Activity rather than in its adapter class
        override fun onDataChanged() {
            if ( itemCount == 0 ) {
                search_people_list.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                retrieving_progress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                empty_search_users_text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                //If was not searching with name field then prompt search with name field
                if ( !searchingWithNameField ) {
                    //Code to add formatting options to the text like underline it
                    val content = SpannableString(getString(R.string.search_with_name_instead))
                    content.setSpan(UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length, 0)
                    change_search_field_text.text = content
                } else
                //If was not searching with username field then prompt search with username field
                {
                    //Code to add formatting options to the text like underline it
                    val content = SpannableString(getString(R.string.search_with_username_instead))
                    content.setSpan(UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length, 0)
                    change_search_field_text.text = content
                }
                change_search_field_text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                //The adapter count is not 0 so show the recyclerView and hide the progress bar, emptyText, Change Search field Text etc.
                search_people_list.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                retrieving_progress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                empty_search_users_text.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                change_search_field_text.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                //Should persist only if there is a result from the query ofCourse
                persistSearchQueryStringAndSearchField(searchQuery)
            }
        }
    }

    adapterCreated = true
    adapter!!.startListening()
    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    //Make the progress bar visible and invisible soon as a document is added to the adapter
    registerAdapterObserver()

    search_people_list.setHasFixedSize(true)
    search_people_list.hasFixedSize()
    search_people_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    search_people_list.adapter = adapter
```

}

So, What I did was made the adapter class open, then created an instance of the Adapter  in the Activity and called the OnDataChanged() method in the Activity which watches for the itemCount in the Adapter. This way I am able to retrieve the correct the adapterCount value.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure **mSnapshots = user!!.snapshots** produces items.

Answer (score 0):

In `fun retrieveDataFromFirestore(searchQuery : String)` after adding items in `adapter!!.firestoreRecyclerAdapter(users!!)`, you are not *notifying* **RecyclerView** to update.

So, don't forget to call

```
adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Your code might looks like this:

```
private fun retrieveDataFromFirestore(searchQuery : String) {

    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    //Assigns the Collection Name from which needs to be queried
    //the where conditions ensure to query a userDocument whose userName starts with the query entered in the searchField
    val userNameQuery = mFirestore.collection(CompanionObjects.USERS_COLLECTION_NAME)
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("userName", searchQuery)
        .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("userName", "$searchQuery\uF7FF")

    //Assigns the query to the User Objects that are related to Firestore
    users = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
        .setQuery(userNameQuery, User::class.java)
        .build()

    //Assigns the Firestore queried data to the search People Adapter
    adapter = SearchPeopleAdapter(users!!)
    registerAdapterObserver()
    adapter!!.firestoreRecyclerAdapter(users!!)
    adapter!!.startListening()
    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged();  //<------- Add this line---------
    search_people_list.setHasFixedSize(true)
    search_people_list.hasFixedSize()
    search_people_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    search_people_list.adapter = adapter
    persistSearchQueryString(searchQuery)

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, it returns 0 even after adding notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Just make sure in `fun firestoreRecyclerAdapter`  `user!!.snapshots` has items and count is not zero

Comment: it does return, I can see the recyclerView bein populated with data but the itemCount says 0. I am trying the registerAdapterDataObserver method but that works only if there are items when queries, I would like to know when the query returns 0 so I can show a text that says "Could not find anything" etc. to the user.....